# How can I convert datetimeoffset to a datetime in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server

I have tried this one, but getting wrong output!

```
declare @createdon datetimeoffset
set @createdon = '2017-09-16 05:50:56.0000000 +05:30'

select 
    convert(datetime2, @createdon, 1)

select 
    convert(datetimeoffset, convert(datetime2, @createdon, 1))
```

Comment: mention your expected output

Comment: select '2017-09-16 11:20:56'

Comment: basically In what Time zone you wan't to convert the Datetime data

Comment: @AlfaizAhmed ,There is a chance to data from multiple nations to that particular table.so can't mention the Time zone.Now i m checking IST alone(UTC +5:30)

Comment: @Guna how will you Recognize which Time Zone Data you Store in Table

Comment: @Guna I had Solution for you But unable to Post here

Answer (score 0):

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), @createdon, 120)
```

Comment: That @createdon varibale value is today's 11.20 am alone..but after converting it shows another time

Comment: Now i have used like this.. 

SELECT DATEADD
(
 MINUTE,
 (DATEPART(HOUR,CAST(RIGHT(@createdon,5) AS DATETIME)) * 60 +
 DATEPART(MINUTE,CAST(RIGHT(@createdon,5) AS DATETIME))),
 CAST(@createdon AS DATETIME)
)